# Mongodb aggregate for nested subdocument field

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get the sum of "Duration" from mongo subdocument's using aggregate,
Here I have `event_id = "5656b3655b9e5c8812000007",` I need to get the sum of "Duration" field by matching the event_id = "5656b3655b9e5c8812000007" in above example.

**Example:**

```
"history" : [
        {
            "timestamp" : "2015-10-26 14:39:15", 
            "event" : "Creation", 
            "createdby" : "Ws", 
            "data" : [
                {
                    "crm_base_contact_id" : "1847", 
                    "crm_imported_files_id" : ""
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : "2015-10-26 15:12:28", 
            "event" : "Task", 
            "createdby" : "Auto-Filter", 
            "data" : [
                {
                    "Campaign ID" : "219", 
                    "Campaign Name" : "ASA", 
                    "Task ID" : "2541639", 
                    "Filter Name" : "ASA", 
                    "Filter ID" : "826"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "event_id" : ObjectId("5656b3655b9e5c8812000007"), 
            "timestamp" : "2015-11-26 08:23:17", 
            "event" : "Session", 
            "createdby" : "ABC", 
            "data" : [
                {
                    "Campaign ID" : "219", 
                    "Task ID" : "2541639", 
                    "viopCalls" : [
                        {
                            "timestamp" : "2015-11-26 08:25:42", 
                            "CallID" : "46", 
                            "Duration" : NumberInt(5), 
                            "TelNumber" : "0685356189"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "timestamp" : "2015-11-26 08:26:13", 
                            "CallID" : "45", 
                            "Duration" : NumberInt(3), 
                            "TelNumber" : "0685356189"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]             
        }
    ], 


Expected output : Duration : 8
```

Please can anyone help me to get the sum of duration column !!!

Comment: is history a key in collection?

Comment: yes its a key in collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use the following aggregate query:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$unwind: '$history'},
  {$match: {'history.event_id': ObjectId("5656b3655b9e5c8812000007")}},
  {$unwind: '$history.data'},
  {$unwind: '$history.data.viopCalls'},
  {$group: {_id: null, duration: {$sum: '$history.data.viopCalls.Duration'}}}
)
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : null, "duration" : 8 }
```